# ExpressJS request body is empty if i don't use multer

Tags: javascript, express, multer

I have this very strange issue with my express app, i simply want to access req.body data that are send through post request via form-data but unfortunately i get undefined error when i try to access those values in request.body but what is strange about this is if i use multer middleware (i used this on another route to upload files) i don't get this error.
i have configured default body parser provided by express.

```
//body pharser
app.use(express.json());
app.use(
  express.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
);

//multer configuration
const ImageUpload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits: { fileSize: 4194304 },
  fileFilter: Imagfilter,
});

//this will return undefined
app.post("/available",(req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body.name);
}

//but this will return the value without any issues
app.post(
  "/available",
  ImageUpload.fields([
    { name: "nicImageFront", maxCount: 1 },
    { name: "nicImageBack", maxCount: 1 },
  ]),
  (req, res) => {
 console.log(req.body.name);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing strange about that.

[FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) objects generate multipart requests. They have to, it is how they support file uploads.

> The FormData interface provides a way to easily construct a set of key/value pairs representing form fields and their values, which can then be easily sent using the XMLHttpRequest.send() method. It uses the same format a form would use if the encoding type were set to "multipart/form-data".

Multer is designed to parse multipart requests.

The `urlencoded` middleware is designed to parse urlencoded requests, not multipart requests.

The `json` middleware is designed to parse JSON encoded requests, not multipart requests.

Comment: Thank You, I get it now, i misunderstood the usage of multer